# Mysql query by weekday

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query by weekday in a given table on a column storing dates. E.g. `select * from MY_TABLE where date_column is 'Monday'`

I saw a `DAYOFWEEK()` function in mysql. But this only seems to manipulate the results of the query.

So is such a query even possible?

Comment: *But this only seems to manipulate the results of the query.* No, it can be used in any place of the query, including the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use weekday name:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%W') = 'Monday';
```

Use weekday index:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date_column) = 2 
-- WHERE WEEKDAY(date_column) = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

The WEEKDAY() function returns the weekday number for a given date.

Note: 0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, 2 = Wednesday, 3 = Thursday, 4 = Friday, 5 = Saturday, 6 = Sunday.

you need to use weekday instead of dayofweek

Comment: No, both functions returns the numeric weekday index.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).